# Purpose of InitializeSimpleMembership annotation on top of class in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have searched the web but haven't found a clear answer as to its true purpose.

I think it has something to do with membership and `WebSecurity` attributes.

Can somebody shed light on its true purpose ?

Comment: first google result : "The InitializeSimpleMembership Attribute ensures that before any membership (login/register) related functionality is run, that the membership database has been created."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Rick_Anderson's blog post [InitializeSimpleMembership Attribute and SimpleMembership Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/15/initializesimplemembership-attribute-and-simplemembership-exceptions.aspx)

> The InitializeSimpleMembership Attribute ensures that before any
>   membership (login/register) related functionality is run, that the
>   membership database has been created. If the database is not yet
>   created, the code will automatically create one. If the simple
>   membership initialization fails, the Web Application can continue to
>   run requests that don’t require membership.